# How to prevent navbar from being covered by content during scrolling?

Tags: html, css

I am building a website with html and css, and I have created a navbar, but it is being overlapped by the content. How would I fix this? Here is the CSS code for the navbar that I've created. It's pretty simple and I am not sure how to resolve this problem!

```css
 #navbar {
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    border:2px solid #FF0E9E;
    background-color:#FF0E9E;
    height:35px;
    width:1300px;
    margin-top:-20px;
    margin-left:-5px;
}
.nav {
    float:right;
    font-size:20px;
    padding-top:5px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: set `z-index` for navbar to a very high value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
#navbar{
    z-index:99999;
}
```